# Video Detection in web view

Tags: android, video, webview

I want to detect a video from different sites when it is playing inside web view. 
And also want to get a resource of that playing video.

I am making an application like video downloader that is why I need that feature 
if anyone has better solution plz tell me

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope my solution would still help,

WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
```